# Cannot create a component with the same name as project in silverlight

Tags: silverlight

I have a project mycomponent. If I create a component helloworld I can put it on main, if I create a component mycomponent and do the same I get this error:

```
Error   1   The type name 'mycomponent'
does not exist in the type
'mycomponent.mycomponent'   C:\...\obj\Debug\MainPage.g.i.cs    41  27  mycomponent
```

Is it impossible ?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, you'd better not use some words in your project name. [Almost] The same goes if your project name ends with .Resources e.g. MyProject.UI.Resources and when you try to load resources in that project it won't work.